# What can I replace the word “I” with in my cover letter?

Tags: business-language, sentence-starts, letter-writing, euphemisms, writing-advice

When proofing my résumé’s cover letter, I found that I am writing *I* way too much. I have read that this is a potential turn-off for employers.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to replace *I* with something else?

This seems to happen more frequently at the beginning of my sentences.

Comment: If you are really overusing _I_ in a way that will turn employers off, the solution is to talk about yourself less, not to find an alternative to the word "I".

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common and understandable problem because the communication really is and has to be largely *about* you, the applicant. Still, here are two tactics for your consideration:

One, shift a lot of the content out of the cover letter and into the résumé, where grammatical predicates are routinely rendered with their grammatical subject, “I,” understood rather than expressed. This will likely make for a very short cover letter; so much the better. The old way was to get up one résumé, professionally formatted, for all potential jobs, and then tailor the cover letters to each prospective employer’s desiderata. Today, with high-powered formatting and typesetting at all of our fingertips, you can tailor the résumé itself to each separate application.

Two, try launching some sentences using the pronoun “you,” meaning the specific potential employer. If *you* hire me, *you* can expect . . . *you* can draw upon these skills and this experience for these *your* purposes. This tactic will lead you to look at the proposed hire from the employer’s point of view, which can lead to manifold improvements in your rhetorical approach, not only in the résumé and cover letter but also in the interview.

Comment: Those are all great suggestions. Do you have anymore examples that I can use? Should I state my experiences and qualifications in the cover letter even though the are listed in my resume? I always have a hard time with this, especially because I am desperate for a job.